# Is there any kind of "Include" list of specific devices on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

We are about to publish application on Google Play. According our contractual obligations first time we can sell it only for new several devices based on specific processor. So, we need to exclude all devices except several ones.

Of course, we check the chip inside app but it's quite big (about 200 MB), so users will not be happy to download it to know they can't play it.

So, what is the best way to make check before downloading? Is there any kind of "Include" list on Google Play?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing provide minimum configuration in description as note so user can compare device configuration with your defined configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify devices in developer dashboard. Once you upload the application, google play will filter device based on you application manifest. You can also exclude devices from supported device list. Check the screenshots. Clicking on `Show devices` will take you to the Device availability screen.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's the way, but I need to exclude over 2000 and leave about 10. Not so pleasant pastime.

Comment: @Anna: Then re-negotiate your contract.

Answer (score 0):

Your app can define required features with the

```
<uses-feature android:name="..." android:required="true" />
```

But this is not possible for cpu. You have the possibility to exclude certain devices in the app store, I think this is your best shot, even though I guess this means you will have to exclude most devices.